# how to reduce time complexity of fibonacci series to n in c

Tags: c

calculating fibonacci no. using recursion

```
fib(n):
    if n==0 or n==1: return 1
    else return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```

In **PYTHON** it takes time complexity between (sq.root 2)^n and 2^n
but using dictionary we can reduce it to n.

So, my question is there something in **C PROGRAMMING** to reduce the time complexity

Comment: Time complexity is not language-dependent. Fibonacci series can be easily calculated in linear time though without any dictionary...

Comment: In C, (using a look-up table i.e. an array filled with pre-computed results), you can reduce it to O(1). ;-) But actually @EugeneSh. is right: any other language with arrays can do it as well.

Comment: Has nothing to do with Python vs C, has everything to do with implementation

Comment: @Scheff Because someday, the OP will get asked this on an exam: no, a lookup table is not an O(1) solution, because it must be finite size, and eventually there will be a value of *N* so high that the speed-up from precalculating the first few billion or trillion values becomes a rounding error. Big Oh has to hold asymptotically for all sufficiently high values of *N*. However, there does happen to be a closed-form expression for the Fibonacci sequence that lets you solve it in O(1) time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

> how to reduce time complexity of fibonacci series to n in c
>    (?)

This is more of an  algorithm issue that an C one.

> question is there something   .... to reduce the time complexity (?)

Yes, use a loop.  Each clarification of `Fibonacci(n)` is `O(n)` complexity.  If desired, amend code to simply print `Fibonacci(i)` at each iteration.

```
unsigned Fibonacci_n(unsigned n) {
  unsigned f[3] = {0, 1, 1};
  while (n > 0) {
    f[2] = f[0] + f[1];
    f[0] = f[1];
    f[1] = f[2];
    n--;
  }
  return f[1];
}

int main(void) {
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%u %u\n", i, Fibonacci_n(i));
  }
}
```

Output

```
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 5
5 8
6 13
7 21
8 34
9 55
```